# R and Keras - problem while fitting model with custom R2 metric

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I need to use the determination coefficient R2 to evaluate the performance of my model on the training set. This metric is not included in the default ones in Keras, so I have to define a custom metric as specified in

https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/metric_binary_accuracy.html

Below I show you my attempt:

```r
library(Metrics)
library(keras)
library(dplyr)

# Calculate mean and standard deviation for scale
mean <- apply(train, 2, mean) 
std <- apply(train, 2, sd)

# Scale and split the data
train_data <- data.frame(scale(train, center = mean, scale = std))
train_data.x <- as.matrix(select(train_data, -c("AvailableBikes")))
train_data.y <- as.matrix(select(train_data, c("AvailableBikes")))

test_data <- data.frame(scale(test, center = mean, scale = std))
test_data.x <- as.matrix(select(test_data, -c("AvailableBikes")))
test_data.y <- as.matrix(select(test_data, c("AvailableBikes")))

# Define R2 custum metric
r2_metric <- custom_metric("R-squared", function(y_true, y_pred){

  SS_res = k_sum(k_square(y_true - y_pred))
  SS_tot = k_sum(k_square(y_true - k_mean(y_true)))

  R2 <- (1- SS_res/(SS_tot + k_epsilon()))

  return(R2)
}) 

# Define a function for build the model
build_model <- function() {
  model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu", input_shape = dim(train_data)[[2]]-1) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1)

  model %>% compile(
    optimizer = "rmsprop",
    loss = "mse",
    metrics = c(r2_metric)
  )
}


num_epochs <- 10


# Train on entire dataset
set.seed(3)
model <- build_model()
model %>% fit(train_data.x, train_data.y,  epochs = num_epochs, batch_size = 32, verbose = 1)
```

The problem arises when I train the model:

```r
model %>% fit(train_data.x, train_data.y,  epochs = num_epochs, batch_size = 32, verbose = 1)
```

The determination coefficient is correctly calculated and updated until the end of the first epoch. Then the training stops returning the following error output:

```
Epoch 1/10
19232/20260 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.7825 - R-squared: 0.1788
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  RuntimeError: Evaluation error: names do not match previous names.
```

What is the origin of this error? Any advice to solve it?
I'm using Keras with R. Thanks in advance.